# Do you like the new layout?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago the layout of SE sites front pages has changed, to a considerable extent IMO.

I know that it is probably the result of a hard and carefully thought process of programmers and site designers, but I find it difficult see improvements from a visual perspective.

Profile icons are much smaller and details about up/down votes, answers etc. are less visible.

In what way is this new layout better or preferable to the previous one?

But probably it is just me.

Comment: If you check Meta.se, it will become apparent you aren't alone. The folks that like the changes seem to be the minority. This has some of the company's rationale and their plans moving forward: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375808/273494

Comment: @ColleenV - thanks for the link…I’m pleased to see that it is not “just me”, but I suspect we will have to get used to it.

Comment: I'm still trying to get used to having the site designs turned into ugly techno-pap. I might become inured to it, but I'll always feel a little pang of loss when I think about it..

Comment: It’s awful. Anyone who disagrees with that is at best tasteless and at worst commitable..

Comment: The information over there appears to me to boil down to "we've made this less useable for you in order to make it more manageable for us."

Comment: For me it is counter-intuitive. I think it sucks.

Comment: No, yet I note that in the month since it was Posted, this Question has been viewed 75 times. What does that say about Members or Meta or anything?